# Painting Multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create a gravity/solar system type simulator in Java, and I'm having trouble painting the circles to the JPanel. Here's my code:

```
public class GUI {

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

 } 
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

ArrayList <body> system = new ArrayList<body>();
public MyPanel() {
    add(new body(1000,20,Color.yellow,0,0,100,100));
    add(new body(10,5,Color.black,5,0,100,50));
}

public void add(body b){system.add(b);}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600,600);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (body b: system) {
        Ellipse2D object = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        object.setFrameFromCenter(
            b.getposx() - b.getSize(),
            b.getposy() - b.getSize(),
            b.getposx(),
            b.getposy());
        g2.setColor(b.getColor());
        g2.fill(object);
    }
}  

}
```

Here is the body class:

```
public class body {
public body(){
    mass = 100;
    size = 1;
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    color = Color.white;
}

public body(int mass, int size, Color color, double velX, double velY, double posX, double posY){
    body.mass = mass;
    body.size = size;
    body.color = color;
    body.velX = velX;
    body.velY = velY;
    body.posX = posX;
    body.posY = posY;

}
//Getters
public int getMass(){return mass;}
public int getSize(){return size;}
public double getvelx(){return velX;}
public double getvely(){return velY;}
public double getposx(){return posX+velX;}
public double getposy(){return posY+velY;}
public Color getColor(){return color;}
//Setters
public static void setMass(int m){mass = m;}
public static void setSize(int s){size = s;}
public static void setvelx(double v){velX = v;}
public static void setvely(double v){velY = v;}
public static void setposx(double p){posX = p;}
public static void setposy(double p){posY = p;}
public static void setColor(Color c){color = c;}

//Member Variables
private static Color color;
private static int mass;
private static int size;
private static double velX;
private static double velY;
private static double posX;
private static double posY;

}
```

So far it'll only paint the last added object. I want to be able to track and display as many bodies as I can, this seems like the simplest and most CPU efficient solution. Is this the best way to do it? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't call, directly or indirectly, repaint from with any paint method

Comment: Can you paste the body class as well? Are you sure the objects aren't just being positioned over the top of each other?

Comment: Well, I'm painting the small one on top of the big one, in which case I would see them both, I would think. I just moved them farther apart in my code, and it didn't show both objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Class names start with upper case characters (ie. it should be `Body`).
2. Don't use static variables and methods in the class. All your `Body` objects share the same value as the last `Body` object created.

Comment: That was it! I guess it makes sense now, I was drawing two objects of the same values. I've just had problems calling methods from other classes before that weren't static methods. Bad habit I guess.

Comment: `I've just had problems calling methods from other classes before that weren't static methods` - this indicates a bad design if that is the only reason for using static methods/variables.